# Hodge-Helmholtz decomposition for 1-form of strategic game

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, hodge-theory, game-theory

This question is motivated by the attempt of decomposing (in a direct sum sense) a strategic game into components in the spirit of Hodge decomposition.

## Preamble

### Combinatorial setting

Candogan et al. (1) work with normal form games in a combinatorial setting. A normal form game $\Gamma = (\mathcal{N}, \mathcal{A}, u)$ is the datum of

- a finite set of players $\mathcal{N} = \{1, \dots, N\}, N \in \mathbb{Z}$
- for each player $i \in \mathcal{N}$, a finite set of actions $\mathcal{A}_i = \{1, \dots, A_i \}, A_i \in \mathbb{Z}$
- for each player $i \in \mathcal{N}$, a utility function $u_i: \mathcal{A} \to \mathbb{R}$, with $\mathcal{A} = \prod_{i \in \mathcal{N}} \mathcal{A}_i$

Given a set of players $\mathcal{N}$ and a set of actions $\mathcal{A}$ the authors build a graph, known in literature as response graph (2), and consider it as a simplicial complex $K$.

For fixed $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{A}$, a game can be then seen (after some manipulation) as a 1-cocahin in $C^1(K, \mathbb{R})$, and can hence be decomposed according to the combinatorial version of Hodge theorem (3):

$$C^1(K, \mathbb{R}) = \text{im } \delta_0 \oplus \text{im } \delta_1^* \oplus \ker{\Delta_1}$$

where the boundary, coboundary and Laplacian operators are defined as usual (see e.g. [this question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4599599/is-the-hodge-decomposition-on-a-simplicial-complex-canonical)).

### Continuous setting - 1

Letcher et al. (4) work with continuous strategy space. Given the number of players and the dimension of the strategy space of each player, the object defining a game in this context can be boiled down to a vector field $\xi: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ in Euclidean space. The authors introduce something they call "Generalized Helmholtz Decomposition", but this turns out to be simply the decomposition of the jacobian matrix of $\xi$ into its symmetric and anti-symmetric parts, $$\text{Jac }\xi = \frac{\text{Jac }\xi + \text{Jac}^T\xi}{2} + \frac{\text{Jac }\xi - \text{Jac}^T\xi}{2} $$ which does not include any discussion on the behavior of $\xi$ at infinity and does not seem to be related to the standard Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition of vector fields [5]. The authors than focus on dynamical properties of the system.

## My question

### Continuous setting - 2

Generically speaking, the primitive object of a strategic game in a continuous setting, e.g.

- mixed extension of normal form games (finite players and finite actions)
- population games (continuous players and finite actions)
- continuos games (finite players and continuous actions)

can be identified with a 1-form, defined, depending on the context, in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or on the standard simplex (or on a product of simplices).

##### What is a good way to tackle the decomposition of 1-form in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on the simplex?

For **Euclidean space**, *"Troyanov (2009) On the Hodge Decomposition in Rn"* seems promising.

For the **simplex without boundary**, there is a rich Hodge theory by Kodaira for non-compact manifolds (*"Kodaira (1949) Harmonic fields in Riemannian manifolds"*), but it seems a bit of an overkill.

For the **simplex with boundary**, I thought to consider it as a

- stratified space (*"Albin P (2016) On the Hodge theory of stratified spaces"*)
- Lipschitz domain (*"Mitrea D (2002) Layer potentials and Hodge decompositions in two dimensional Lipschitz domains."*)
- convex domain (*"Geng J, Shen Z (2010) The Neumann problem and Helmholtz decomposition in convex domains."*)

but before diving in some technical theory I'm not familiar with I'd like to ask for a suggestion.

---

1. Candogan O, Menache I, Ozdaglar A, Parrilo PA (2011) Flows and
   Decompositions of Games: Harmonic and Potential Games. Mathematics
   of Operations Research 36(3):474–503.
2. Biggar O, Shames I (2023) The graph structure of two-player games.
   Sci Rep 13(1):1833.
3. Jiang X, Lim LH, Yao Y, Ye Y (2011) Statistical ranking and
   combinatorial Hodge theory. Mathematical Programming 127(1):203–244.
4. Letcher A, Balduzzi D, Racaniere S, Martens J, Foerster J, Tuyls K, Graepel T (2019) Differentiable Game Mechanics.
5. Bhatia H, Norgard G, Pascucci V, Bremer PT (2013) The Helmholtz-Hodge Decomposition—A Survey. IEEE Trans. Visual. Comput. Graphics 19(8):1386–1404.